# Why does `gnuplot` plot look ragged?

Tags: background, gnuplot, noise, ragged

I have a data file with six pairs of XY-data. I want to plot the six functions in one graphic. But when I do so the lines look kind of ragged.

Here is my code:

```
set terminal pdf
set output 'test.pdf'

set xrange [10:150]
set yrange [-150:5000]

set xlabel "2 {/Symbol q} / °"
set ylabel "int. / a.u." offset .8,0

plot 'test.xy' using ($1):($2)   notitle   w lines ls 2, \
     'test.xy' using ($3):($4)   notitle   w lines ls 3, \
     'test.xy' using ($5):($6)   notitle   w lines ls 4, \
     'test.xy' using ($7):($8)   notitle   w lines ls 5, \
     'test.xy' using ($9):($10)  notitle   w lines ls 6, \
     'test.xy' using ($11):($12)   notitle   w lines ls 7
```

[image: picture of the resulting plot]

As you can see the background is uncontrollably frayed. Obviously this phenomenon doesn't appear in the data, and when I'm only plotting a smaller sector (e.g. x1=25, x2=32) the background is not frayed like this.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Please post your data file, or at least a small part of it that is sufficient to show this behavior. How many lines does your data file contain?

Comment: What are x1 and x2?   Your plot command should produce 7 different lines, so why is there only one line visible in the sample plot?  Is it really 7 superimposed lines?

Comment: [Here is the data file I used.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmVJ9khmZ5Gysj__Hd725vq27xOy) It should be about 14000 lines.   I was refering to the xrange. I meant to say "if I set xrange [25:32] the background is not frayed like this."   And yes the six graphs are very similar.